# How to require the credit card field in Stripe Elements fields?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

My issue is that I have a form that submits with the credit card field being blank.

I have the credit card field combined with another form which is where the issue lies.

So my question is, how do I require the credit card field using JS or Ruby?

Here's the form and javascript:

```
<%= form_for([@listing, @order], html: {id: "Orders"}) do |form| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :name, "Who's the Order for?" %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control", required: true  %>
  </div>

  <script
    src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/">
  </script>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="card-element">
        Credit or debit card
      </label>
      <div id="card-element" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">

    <%= form.submit "asdf", class:"ripple-effect", id:"button-element" %>
    <!-- <button id="button-element" class="ripple-effect">Submit Payment for </button> EITHER OF THESE BUTTONS WORK WITH THE FORM-->
  </div>
  <span class="token"></span>
  </form>
  <% end %>

<script>
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_413253....f0B8');

  var elements = stripe.elements();

  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      lineHeight: '24px',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  card.mount('#card-element');

  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });

    });

    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {

      var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
      var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
      form.appendChild(hiddenInput);


      ["brand", "exp_month", "exp_year", "last4"].forEach(function(field) {
         addFieldToForm(form, token, field);

    });

      // Submit the form
      form.submit();

    }
</script>
```

Here's the orders controller create method, which is now a bit messy:

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    @seller = @listing.user

    @order.listing_id = @listing.id
    @order.buyer_id = current_user.id
    @order.seller_id = @seller.id

    if @order.valid?
      begin
        @amount = 500
        token = params[:stripeToken]
        payment_form = params[:payment_form]

        charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
          :source  => 'tok_visa',
          :amount      => @amount,
          :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
          :currency    => 'usd'
        })

      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
        flash[:error] = e.message
        redirect_to new_charge_path
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        if user_signed_in?
          @user = current_user
          OrderMailer.order_email(@user, @order).deliver
          format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
          if buyer_signed_in?
            @user = current_buyer
            OrderMailer.order_email(@user, @order).deliver
            format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        if user_signed_in?
          format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully uploaded.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
        if buyer_signed_in?
          format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'Order was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name, :address, :city, :state, :image, :video, :description, :order_status)
    end

    def deny_to_visitors
      redirect_to root_path unless user_signed_in? or buyer_signed_in?
    end

    def user_orders
      @order.buyer_id = current_buyer.id or current_user
    end

end
```

When I press submit, both the Order gets created and the API request is successful.  How can I require the credit card field to be validated with either ruby or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

As @Auriga has pointed out, credit card validation is done by stripe during the tokenization process.

However, Stripe Element does provide a way for you verify the fields and give more meaningful feedback to your frontend user.

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#input-validation

Comment: the issue i think it mostly in the controller or similar.  because on stripes side, it works... but i dont need to fill out or complete the credit card information to input the order.. even when i use the "<button id="button-element" ... >" as the input

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js template

Try adding `window.onload = function () {
 var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_413253....f0B8');
.............................................. // UR CODE
}`

You can see in the docs example it should alert if the user submits a card blank. You can't verify it in the backend as stripe.js in the frontend creates a credit card token for you to use as security

Comment: the window.onload = function () { .... } didn't do it... it works separately when i dont have it embeded within the @orders form_for... that's (when i added the stripe code into the order controller) when the issues start happening.

Comment: all of it works somewhat properly.. the token is sent to stripe and the order is created.  ideally i would want the order to be created only if the stripe payment is successful but first and foremost, i need to figure out why i'm even sending the token payment to stripe if the credit card field isn't filled out